# Android bluetooth: A thread started from UI thread blocks the UI thread

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am learning Android bluetooth programming. I copied most of this code from Google's Android developer website for learning. The idea is listening for connection on server is done in a new thread without blocking the UI thread. When connection request is received then connection is done on another thread and finally communication is done on another thread.

The problem is when I start the listening thread from UI thread, it block automatically and no UI is displayed (freezes). Here is the sample code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...

    badapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (badapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No bluetooth device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!badapter.isEnabled()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is disabled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    pairedDevices = new HashMap<String, String>();
    discoveredDevices = new HashMap<String, String>();

    showDevices();
    registerBroadcastReceiver();

    //this thread blocks UI thread
    ListenThread listen = new ListenThread();
    listen.run();
}
```

And the listen thread:

```
public class ListenThread extends Thread {
    MainActivity main;
    CommunicateThread communicateThread;
    private final BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;

    public ListenThread() {
        main = MainActivity.getInstance();

        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = main.badapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(main.NAME, main.MYUUID);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            main.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(main, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        serverSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        //keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                main.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(main, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                //call communication thread once connection is established
                communicateThread = new CommunicateThread(socket);
                communicateThread.run();

                try {
                    serverSocket.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    main.handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(main, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think need to use `listen.start();` for starting Thread instead of calling run method

Comment: How silly of me! Could that be the cause?

Comment: That is the cause. Does that mean when I call run, it is executing in the UI thread instead?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling listen.run() on the main thread which makes it run on the main thread. You should call listen.start() which will spawn off a separate thread where the run() method will be executed.

The Runnable given to the handler will be executed on the main thread though as the Handler is for the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I understand is that every time you make a hardware call, in this case, the Bluetooth, you should do it in another thread. I moved the isEnabled() call to other thread and it solved the problem.